# How to view IntelliJ console if program exit code was non-zero?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij IDEA Community 2020.1

When I try to run this super-simple example code:

```
public class testConsole {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Wish I could see this important info");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

I see the important message flash up in the console for a split-second, then the screen immediately switches to an error about the non-zero exit code:

```
Execution failed for task ':testConsole.main()'.
> Process 'command 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.7.0_71/bin/java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Is there any way to switch back to the console so I can see what was printed to sysout?

Comment: You may click on the root element of the messages tree on left panel.

Comment: For me the log did not disappear at all.

Comment: @Magnilex Even when you exit with non-zero exit code?

Comment: @localhost With your code, yes.

Comment: @Magnilex When I tried that code in an empty project it worked as you describe. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Console button] I discovered if I click on the top red exclamation point, I can then scroll up to see the sysout.

I think what was happening is to do with having a warning in another part of the project. When I moved that code into a new project that has no compilation errors, the sysout remains even when there's a non-zero exit code.